# Choosing a CIDR Block

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpc

I am new to AWS and learning about IP addresses and CIDR Block.
i am reading that we should choose a CIDR Block according to our needs.

my Question is :-  why can\t we just use a CIDR Block like **192.168.0.0/16** which encompasses so many ip addresses in for every VPC? does it give some overhead or some performance problem or is it paid?

thanks

Comment: Its not paid nor it affects the performance.

Answer (score 1):

It’s perfectly ok to use 192.168.0.0/16 VPC cidr block as it’s private cidr block. Also there is no performance overhead or no payment need to be made.